# Where do I put code in an Objective-C class if I want it to run as soon as the class is called?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Sorry. This is a really basic question but I can't find the answer anywhere. I just want to cast variables as soon as an iOS app starts up so I don't have too much in the button action.

Comment: Classes don't get "called". There should be some sort of delegate method that gets called when your app gets initialized - just check the documentation for everything XCode generates in a new project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to perform some operations on class level rather than instantiation level, you can either overload `+ (void)load` or `+ (void)initialize`:

```
+ (void)load {
    // codes will run as soon as the application is loaded into the runtime
}

+ (void)initialize {
    // codes will run the first time this class is being referred to in the application execution
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "instantiated" instead of "called", override `- (id)init` in the .m implementation file of the class, like so:

```
- (id)init {

     if (self = [super init]) {
          // your custom code here
     }
     return self;
}
```